# Since homebrew updated me to php@7.1 from php71 my php extensions have become disabled

Tags: php, homebrew

Since homebrew updated me to php@7.1 from php71 my php extensions have become disabled:

- imagick
- opcache
- xdebug

I've read that these are now included and cannot be installed separately. Before, running `brew install php70-opcache` etc. enabled the extensions.

How do I re-enable these PHP extensions?

See: [macOS php71 became php@7.1 with brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579961/macos-php71-became-php7-1-with-brew).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, I ran:

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.1
```

Then I added the below lines to the bottom of *~/.bash_profile*

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"
```

Reloaded with `source ~/.bash_profile`. Then, I restarted PHP.

Now when I run `php --version`, I see that my extensions are back.