# Unable to install/enable gmp on mac os php@7.1

Tags: php-gmp

I am trying to install gmp extension for mac as I get this Problem while fetching some dependencies from github

> Problem 1
>       - mdanter/ecc v0.3.2 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.

I have tried brew formulas like

```
brew install php71-gmp
```

Have followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579961/macos-php71-became-php7-1-with-brew) but unable to get it to work.

I am using Xampp, `which php` is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php`

OS - macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Have you tried adding extension=php_gmp.so to the php.ini file ?

Comment: @WilfredClement I am unable to get that

Comment: Unable to get the file or unable to understand my comment ? 

Let me rephrase, Can you try adding "extension=php_gmp.so"  to the php.ini file

Comment: @WilfredClement Unable to get the file "php_gmp.so"

Comment: Search for the file - php.ini.default and change it to php.ini and try making the changes which I've suggested

Usually, can be found in /etc folder

Comment: @WilfredClement I do know the file php.ini, but "php_gmp.so" file itself is missing, Where from I can download that?

Comment: That isn't a file, I am asking you to add in a line in the php.ini file

"extension=php_gmp.so"

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579961/macos-php71-became-php7-1-with-brew). The first answer might be able to fix your problem